# Wifi hotspot name not updated on hotspot creation in desire

Tags: android, networking, wifi

I am using the following code to enable wfi hotspot in HTC desire running Android 2.2.

Access Point(Hotspot) is created but the access point name/hotspot name/SSID is not what I specified in the code(MyWifiAP).

Anyhelp on this?

**CODE :**

```
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
Method[] wmMethods = wifi.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
Log.d(TAG, "enableMobileAP methods " + wmMethods.length);
for(Method method: wmMethods){
    Log.d(TAG, "enableMobileAP method.getName() " + method.getName());
    if(method.getName().equals("setWifiApEnabled")) {
        WifiConfiguration netConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
        netConfig.SSID = "MyWifiAP";
        netConfig.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN);
        netConfig.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
        netConfig.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
        netConfig.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "enableMobileAP try: ");
            method.invoke(wifi, netConfig, enabled);
            if (netConfig.wepKeys!=null && netConfig.wepKeys.length>=1)
            Log.d(TAG, "enableMobileAP key : " + netConfig.wepKeys[0]);
            Log.d(TAG, "enableMobileAP enabled: ");
            mIsWifiEnabled = enabled;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "enableMobileAP failed: ", e);
        }
    }
}.
```

Comment: Were you able to find any solution? :s

Comment: @dheeps, would you share the full source code? :D

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to get this working. One thing is that your SSID is definitely wrong. It should be in quotes "\"MyWifiAP"\". Good luck.